Isometric Rendering Doesn't Align
I've been starting to experiment with 2D rendering, in particular isometric rendering.
So far I've been having issues getting my tiles to line up.
I am currently writing this in Rust using the Bevy engine.
Here is my Cartesian to isometric coordinate conversion function:
pub fn to_isometric(cartesian_coordinates: Vec3, map_tile_width: f32, map_tile_height: f32) -> Vec3 {
Vec3 {
    x: (cartesian_coordinates.y * map_tile_width / 2.0) + (cartesian_coordinates.x * map_tile_width / 2.0),
    y: ((cartesian_coordinates.x * map_tile_height / 2.0) - (cartesian_coordinates.y * map_tile_height / 2.0)),
    z: cartesian_coordinates.z
    }
}

Below is the code used to spawn the tiles into the world:
pub fn world_setup(
mut commands: Commands,
asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) {

let grass_sprite = asset_server.load("./textures/grass_block.png");
let dirt_sprite = asset_server.load("./textures/dirt_brick.png");

let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
for x in -10..10 {
    for y in -10..10 {
        let z = 0;
        if rng.gen_bool(0.7) {
            commands.spawn(
                StaticBundle::new(
                    crate::util::math::to_isometric(Vec3::new((x) as f32, (y) as f32, z as f32), 32.0, 32.0),
                    Thing::Grass,
                    grass_sprite.clone()
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            commands.spawn(
                StaticBundle::new(
                    to_isometric(Vec3::new(x as f32, y as f32, z as f32), 32.0, 32.0),
                    Thing::Dirt,
                    dirt_sprite.clone()
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is what an individual tile look like:

Below is an image of what my current rendering looks like.

Any ideas why the tiles are not rendering as a smooth diamond of tiles?
I'm looking for something like this:


Looks like 100x100 is too large to fit in your view (or the portion you've cropped to show here), and your map_tile_height parameter is counting not just the height of the diamond surface of the tile, but also its front edge.

@DMGregory I've updated the image for clarity, and reduced the number of tiles for the purposes of this question.
I'm not quite sure I understand your comment about the map tile height. What are you referring to by "its front edge"?

The height of the dirt part, rather than the grass part.

Isn't that expected though? I'm trying to render the entire tile after all. That tile just might be covered up by another tile that is in front of it.

To get it covered up like that, you want the vertical spacing between tiles to be based on the height of the flat diamond on top only. If you count the dirt, you'll show the dirt.


I'm looking for something like this:


Then just adjust your Y shift to be smaller, e.g. 24px instead of 32px (I didnt measure the exact "tile thickness").
The code place responsible is probably here:
y: ((cartesian_coordinates.x - cartesian_coordinates.y) 
    * map_tile_height / 2.0
    / 32.0 * 24.0) // Position on Y by 24px instead of 32px

Make sure to use Z-buffer or draw from back to front, to cover up the dirt.
